# Html translator with JQuery and XML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, multilingual

I would like to make a html side multilingual. I know it's not the best approach to do it with text files, but for my project it's the best solution.

When the web page loads I would like to have a `.js script` exchange the content with class `tr`. Every text gets an `id` which is also inside the `xml`.

So: Page load > script loads xml > read content of language > iterate through every element with class `tr` > exchange element with its corresponding text in `xml` (related by `id`)

**XML:**

```
<translations>
  <de>
    <item id="test">
      Dieser Text soll übersetzt werden          
    </item>
    <item id="test2">
      Dieser Text soll auch funktionieren
    </item>
  </de>
  <en>
    <item id="test">
      This test text shall be translated          
    </item>
    <item id="test2">
      This shall also work
    </item>
  </en>
</translations>
```

**Code:**

```
/// <reference path="jquery.js" />

$(document).ready(function() {

var lang = 'de'; //shall be choosable later

var xmlDoc = //read language.xml file here;

var xml = jQuery.parseXML(xmlDoc);

$xml.find(lang).each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    // translate all translatable elements
    $('.tr').each(function(i) {
      //find matching id ?! and set text
    });
  }
}
});
});

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tr" id="test">This test text shall be translated</div>
<p class="tr" id="test2">This shall also work</p>
```

I'm really a beginner with javascript and therefore I really need help to understand and to reach my goal.

**Note:** my project do not require a server. It shall be a "manual" so its all local.

Comment: This is done much more appropriately on the serverside. Set a cookie with the language, and let the server generate the content.

Comment: My project do not require a server. It shall be a "manual". So its just local.

Comment: Then how are you doing ajax requests, which would require http:// ?

Comment: Thx, I was not aware of that. So, shall I then use JQuery get() function to get my `.xml` content?

Comment: `$.get` is using ajax, and you'd have to run some sort of webserver software to use it, or change the default settings of your browser to support ajax requests for `file://` protocol.

Comment: Is there nor possibility to read xml files "offline/local"? Is there then any other approach to translate my pages?